# "AND &" operator work fine but "OR |" and Either-OR "^" always true

Tags: php, operators

I am using logical operators to test variables but **AND &** operator work fine but **OR |** and Either-OR **^** always true.
Why?

```
$a = 6;
$b = 6;

if ($a OR $b == 3) {
    echo 'true <br />';
}
else {
    echo 'false <br />';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your syntax.

You need to look at the expression separately.

```
if($a) OR if($b == 3)
```

is what you're doing.

What you want is:

```
if($a == 3 || $b == 3)
```

If you look at `$a` by itself, any value except for 0 will return `true` making the entire equation `true` thanks to the `OR`

Answer (score 3):

Because you have to OR to Boolean results - you're reading it too much like English.

```
if ($a == 3 || $b == 3)
```

rather than

```
if ($a OR $b == 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of precedence - see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php for more details here.

Both the other answers give you the code you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = true
$b = true
if($a and $b)   TRUE if both $a and $b are TRUE.
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php